# Prove that :The set of all events that are independent from one event A, need not be a σ-field.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

Question:

### Consider a probability space (Ω, F, P), and let A be an event(element of F).

### Let g be the set of all events(the events denote by $g_{i}$ ) that are independent from A.

### How to show that g need not be a σ-field?

I know that a σ-field f has following properties:

1. ∅∈f
2. If A∈f then $A^{C}$∈f
3. If $A_{i}$∈f for every i∈$\mathbb{N}$,then $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty }$$A_{i}$∈f

And I know that for a field $f_{0}$, the third property is

3. If A∈$f_{0}$ and B∈$f_{0}$,then A$\bigcup$B∈$f_{0}$.

For $g_{i}$, the properties 1. and 2. are easy to varify. But I don't know how to answer the question,show  g need not be a σ-field(And sholud I use the property 3.?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* It is true that if $\{A_i\}_{i\in \Bbb N}$ is a sequence of disjoint evets all of which are independent from $E$, then $\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N}A_i$ is independent from $E$. Let's then call $(3^-)$ the property of a family of subsets of being closed under union of countable sequences of disjoint elements.

Let's also call $(3^{--})$ the property of a family of subsets of being closed under finite intersections; equivalently, of being closed under intersections of pairs of elements. Some would say that the pair version is slightly weaker, because they adopt the convention that $\bigcap\emptyset$ is the whole space; however $(1)\land (2)\land (3^{--})$ is the same condition no matter which choice of $(3^{--})$ you make.

Finally, notice that a family which satisfies $(1)\land (2)\land (3^-)\land (3^{--})$ **is** a $\sigma$-algebra, via the trick $\bigcup_{i\in \Bbb N}A_i=\bigcup_{i\in \Bbb N}\left(A_i\cap \bigcap_{j=0}^{i-1}A_j^C\right)$.

**Therefore** your only hope is to find three events $A$, $B$, $C$ in some probability space such that $\{A,B\}$ are independent, $\{B,C\}$ are independent and $\{A\cap C,B\}$ are not independent.

Comment: Consider a single toss of a coin. Define events  A={1,2,3},B={odd number},C={3,4}. A∩C={3}.                                                            
Then {A,B} are independent ,{B,C} are independent,{A∩C,B}are not independent. So property (3)  is not conformed,thus the set is not a σ -algebra.                                                                                          
 I think this is what you mean ,did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @mewait Do you mean "dice roll"? My coins don't have four faces (and dices usually have six, unless otherwise stated).

Comment: Yes,I mean dice roll. B={odd number}={1,3,5].

Comment: Then $P(A\cap B)=\frac13\ne P(A)P(B)=\frac14$. It should work with $A=\{2,3\}$.